# How to insert the output of ANTLR to the lucene flexible query parser

Tags: parsing, lucene, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer

recently i had seen a grammar for Lucene query in ANTLRv4.this was the link to that repository`https://github.com/lrowe/lucenequery/blob/master/lucenequery/StandardLuceneGrammar.g4` . using this i had generated the lexer and parser.

but now i don't know how to send this output to Lucene query parser. if anyone knows please explain the process of doing it.thanks in advance :-).

Comment: The Lucene query parser (at least based upon it's name) should do the parsing for you.  There should be no need for you to do your own parsing just to hand something to the other parser.  The ANTLR grammar would be of us to someone who wants to parse a Lucene query and do something with it (perhaps some transfoamation, or looking to implement their own search). I would expect you pas the simple source to the Lucene parser.

Comment: thanks for the response :). yes Lucene query parser alone can parse the query and search the documents. the intention was to modify the Lucene syntax (or i want to create my own grammar and produce AST for that using ANTLRv4 ). then to pass it to the Lucene.(want to combine the power of Lucene and ANTLRv4). so that i can write my own  grammar for Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR doesn't have a built-in "unparsed" to convert your ParseTree (ANTLR produces parse trees, not ASTs).

That said, the ANTLR eco-system has a couple of tools that could be applicable to your case.

The first, and simplest, is [TokenStreamRewriter](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenStreamRewriter.html).  This allows you to create a series of instructions for modifications to your input stream, and that have the modifications applied to produce a new String.  There is no need to modify an AST, etc.  You can also use ANTLR's [XPath](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/xpath/XPath.html) functionality to find specific nodes on your parse tree that match a particular pattern.

Here's an example that looks for expressions like `aBool == TRUE` and just simplifies them to `abool` (it's not a full working example, but should give a feel for how simple it is to use a `TokenStreamRewriter`).

(Note: this is extracted from a tutorial I put together so it just works on small intervals of the token stream, but you can use a `TokenStreamRewriter` to store up a large set of changes to the entire input, and then call `rewriter.getText()` to get a modified version of your input.)

```java
    TokenStreamRewriter rewriter = new TokenStreamRewriter(parser.getInputStream());

    private static final String ANY_EXPR_XPATH = "//expr";
    private ParseTreePattern eqTruePattern = 
       parser.compileParseTreePattern("<expr> == <TRUE>", LittleCalcParser.RULE_expr);

    @Override
    public Void visitRefactorUtil(RefactorUtilContext ctx) {
        var contentInterval = new Interval( //
                ctx.O_CURLY().getSymbol().getTokenIndex() + 1, //
                ctx.C_CURLY().getSymbol().getTokenIndex() - 1);
        var pName = "simplify" + ctx.getStart().getTokenIndex();

        eqTrue(ctx, pName);

        System.out.println(rewriter.getText(pName, contentInterval));
        return null;
    }

    private void eqTrue(RefactorUtilContext ctx, String pName) {
        for (var match : eqTruePattern.findAll(ctx, ANY_EXPR_XPATH)) {
            var matchCtx = (EqualityExprContext) (match.getTree());
            rewriter.delete(pName, matchCtx.op, matchCtx.rhs.getStop());
        }
    }
```

If you're needs are more complex than you can accomplish with a `TokenStreamRewriter` (and don't discount it too quickly, it's pretty powerful).  If you really need to transform your parse tree to an AST and perform AST transformations before you can write the results out, then it's probably worth taking a look at the tool that ANTLR uses to write generate it's code.  That would be [StringTemplate](https://www.stringtemplate.org).  There's more to learn to get going with it than just using `TokenStreamRewriter` but it's very powerful for code generation from an object graph.

That said, if your AST maps relatively closely to the grammar (pretty likely), and you’re not really concerned about formatting (also, likely).  It can be pretty trivial to write a `toSource()` method for each AST node type, that will recursively gather the `toSource()`results of child nodes and generate your source code without bothering with learning `StringTemplate`(probably passing around a `StringBuilder` to do so efficiently).